# multiple windows opening on clicking button. how to prevent it

Tags: python, tkinter

how to stop opening the same window multiple time when the button clicked for below code. in this I'm using multiprocessing.

on button click event I'm getting issue like screenshot

[image]

[github repo](https://github.com/Vignesh960/multiple_windows_opening/blob/main/threads.py)

```
root = Tk()
root.title("PDF Reader")
root.geometry("500x300+500+300")
root.maxsize(width=None, height=None)
root.resizable(False, False)
def dostuff():
    if (__name__ == "__main__"):
        try:
            folder = folderPath.get()

            if folder != "":
                if (os.path.exists(folder)):
                    run_btn['state'] = DISABLED
                    msg = "Please wait... Process being done.\n Dont close the app."
                    label = Label(root, text=msg, foreground="red")
                    label.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=20)
                    # label.pack()
                    label.update()
                    #root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_exit)
                    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", disable_event)

                    pdfs_list = get_listof_files(folder, "pdf")

                    with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
                        failed = manager.list()
                        if pdfs_list:

                            p = multiprocessing.Pool(5)
                            p.map(partial(get_total_txt, failed),
                                  pdfs_list)

                            # p.close()
                            # Process.join(p)
                        # print(failed)
                        label.destroy()
                        suss_files_count = len(pdfs_list)-len(failed)
                        print("Out of {} files {} Succeeded and {} files found without data {} Files Without Grid Numbers and {} loaded.".format(
                            len(pdfs_list), suss_files_count, len(
                                failed), len(No_grid_number),
                            str(round(suss_files_count/(len(pdfs_list))*100, 2))+"%"))
                        msg = "\nProcess has been Completed Sucessfully..!\n Out of {} files {} Succeeded and {} files found without data.\n Please check Log for More info.".format(
                            len(pdfs_list), suss_files_count, len(
                                failed), len(No_grid_number))
                        label = Label(root, text="", foreground="green")
                        label.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=20)
                        # label.pack()
                        label.update()
                        label = Label(root, text=msg, foreground="green")
                        label.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=20)
                        # label.pack()
                        label.update()
                        time.sleep(5)
                        label.destroy()

                    end_time = datetime.now()
                    print('Duration: {} Minutes'.format(end_time - start_time))
                    run_btn['state'] = NORMAL
                else:
                    messagebox.showerror(
                        "Path Not Found", "Selected path or directory doesn't exists: "+folder)
            else:
                messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "Please Select path")

                # print(folder)
        except AttributeError as attbe:
            messagebox.showerror("AttributeError", str(attbe))
        except FileNotFoundError as fne:
            messagebox.showerror("TypeError", str(fne))
            run_btn['state'] = NORMAL
            #print(fne, folder)
        except TypeError as TError:
            messagebox.showerror("TypeError", str(TError))
            run_btn['state'] = NORMAL


folderPath = StringVar()
a = Label(root, text="\nChoose Path:", font=('Arial'))
a.grid(row=0, column=0)
e = Entry(root, textvariable=folderPath, width=50)
e.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=35)
btn_browse = ttk.Button(root, text="Browse", command=getFolderPath, padding=5)
btn_browse.grid(row=3, column=1)
""""whenever the button is clicked, a new thread will be created and started """
run_btn = Button(root, text="Run", command=lambda: Thread(target=dostuff).start(),
                 width=30, height=2, padx=10)
run_btn.grid(row=4, column=0)
# root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_exit)
# root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: (
#     run_btn.config(state="disabled"), root.destroy()))

root.lift()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: (1) Do not put the `"__name__" == "__main__"` block inside a function.  Either the function will be called, or it won't.  (2) You cannot do any UI stuff from a thread, nor can you do UI stuff across processes.  Your lambda must call a function, NOT start a thread.  (3) You don't want to mix multithreading and multiprocessing.  Why do you think you need multiprocessing here?

Comment: i want to process multiple files simultaneously those files data will be loaded into DB

Comment: FIRST, make it work.  THEN decide whether it is fast enough or not.  Premature optimization is a sin.

Comment: its working normally when i don't use processing, but its slower in execution all files, then implemented multiprocessing then I'm facing this. Please provide any guidence.

Comment: ALL of your "one time only" code, and that includes EVERYTHING that references tkinter or the `root` window, needs to be in a `main` function that only gets called when `__name__ == "__main__"`.  Remember that every new process that starts re-executes your script from the top.  That's why you get so many windows.

Comment: Can you provide what changes do I need to do in the above

Answer (score 0):

Here's the kind of structure you need.  This still doesn't work, because I don't have the functions in your module and there are some errors in your code, but this shows the structure:

```
import os
import glob
import multiprocessing
from tkinter import *

def get_total_txt(f,pdf):
    f.append(pdf)
def get_listof_files(folder,ext):
    return glob.glob( folder+"/*."+ext)

def getFolderPath():
    folder_selected = filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir="")
    folderPath.set(folder_selected)

def on_exit():
    """When you click to exit, this function is called"""
    if run_btn['state'] == DISABLED:
        if messagebox.askyesno("Exit", "Are you want to quit the application? Currently process being in running state."):
            root.destroy()
            sys.exit(0)
    else:
        if messagebox.askyesno("Exit", "Are you want to quit the application?"):
            root.destroy()

def disable_event():
    messagebox.showinfo( "Processing", "Please wait until process being done.")

def dostuff():
    folder = folderPath.get()

    if folder != "":
        if os.path.exists(folder):
            run_btn['state'] = DISABLED
            msg = "Please wait... Process being done.\n Dont close the app."
            label = Label(root, text=msg, foreground="red")
            label.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=20)
            label.update()
            #root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_exit)
            root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", disable_event)

            pdfs_list = get_listof_files(folder, "pdf")

            with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
                failed = manager.list()
                if pdfs_list:
                    p = multiprocessing.Pool(5)
                    p.map(partial(get_total_txt, failed),
                          pdfs_list)

            label.destroy()
            suss_files_count = len(pdfs_list)-len(failed)
            print("Out of {} files {} Succeeded and {} files found without data {} Files Without Grid Numbers and {} loaded.".format(
                len(pdfs_list), suss_files_count, len(
                    failed), len(No_grid_number),
                str(round(suss_files_count/(len(pdfs_list))*100, 2))+"%"))
            msg = "\nProcess has been Completed Sucessfully..!\n Out of {} files {} Succeeded and {} files found without data.\n Please check Log for More info.".format(
                len(pdfs_list), suss_files_count, len(
                    failed), len(No_grid_number))
            label = Label(root, text="", foreground="green")
            label.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=20)
            # label.pack()
            label.update()
            label = Label(root, text=msg, foreground="green")
            label.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=20)
            # label.pack()
            label.update()
            time.sleep(5)
            label.destroy()

            end_time = datetime.now()
            print('Duration: {} Minutes'.format(end_time - start_time))
            run_btn['state'] = NORMAL
        else:
            messagebox.showerror(
                "Path Not Found", "Selected path or directory doesn't exists: "+folder)
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "Please Select path")

def main():
    global root
    global folderPath
    global run_btn
    root = Tk()
    root.title("PDF Reader")
    root.geometry("500x300+500+300")
    root.maxsize(width=None, height=None)
    root.resizable(False, False)
    folderPath = StringVar()
    a = Label(root, text="\nChoose Path:", font=('Arial'))
    a.grid(row=0, column=0)
    e = Entry(root, textvariable=folderPath, width=50)
    e.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=35)
    #btn_browse = ttk.Button(root, text="Browse", command=getFolderPath, padding=5)
    btn_browse = Button(root, text="Browse", command=getFolderPath)
    btn_browse.grid(row=3, column=1)
    """"whenever the button is clicked, a new thread will be created and started """
    run_btn = Button(root, text="Run", command=dostuff, width=30, height=2, padx=10)
    run_btn.grid(row=4, column=0)
# root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_exit)
# root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: (
#     run_btn.config(state="disabled"), root.destroy()))

    root.lift()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```